# Error: While resolving module, the Haste package was found. the module could not be found within the package

Tags: java, android, typescript, react-native, react-native-turbomodule

I am trying the new arch of react native. I have enabled it in my `gradle.properties` file. This error is for android only and I have not tried iOS yet.

I am following the exact sample of Calculator mentioned over [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/the-new-architecture/pillars-turbomodules).

I get an error saying

```
error: Error: While resolving module `rtn-calculator/js/NativeCalculator.js`, the Haste package `rtn-calculator` was found. However the module `js/NativeCalculator.js` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/RTNCalculator/js/NativeCalculator.js(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/RTNCalculator/js/NativeCalculator.js/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
    at resolveHasteName (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:173:9)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:63:20)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:111:31)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:260:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:177:21)
    at Graph._resolveDependencies (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:432:35)
    at Graph._processModule (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:218:38)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Graph._addDependency (/Users/transformhub/Desktop/rnapp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:314:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
```

The complete repo is [here](https://github.com/PritishSawant/RnMyAppNewArch)

Below is sample code

```
NativeCalculator.ts

import type {TurboModule} from 'react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/RCTExport';
import {TurboModuleRegistry} from 'react-native';

export interface Spec extends TurboModule {
  add(a: number, b: number): Promise<number>;
}

export default TurboModuleRegistry.get<Spec>('RTNCalculator') as Spec | null;


package com.rtncalculator;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.module.model.ReactModuleInfo;
import com.facebook.react.module.model.ReactModuleInfoProvider;
import com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CalculatorPackage extends TurboReactPackage {

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public NativeModule getModule(String name, ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      if (name.equals(CalculatorModule.NAME)) {
          return new CalculatorModule(reactContext);
      } else {
          return null;
      }
  }


  @Override
  public ReactModuleInfoProvider getReactModuleInfoProvider() {
      return () -> {
          final Map<String, ReactModuleInfo> moduleInfos = new HashMap<>();
          moduleInfos.put(
                  CalculatorModule.NAME,
                  new ReactModuleInfo(
                          CalculatorModule.NAME,
                          CalculatorModule.NAME,
                          false, // canOverrideExistingModule
                          false, // needsEagerInit
                          true, // hasConstants
                          false, // isCxxModule
                          true // isTurboModule
          ));
          return moduleInfos;
      };
  }
}

package com.rtncalculator;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.rtncalculator.NativeCalculatorSpec;

public class CalculatorModule extends NativeCalculatorSpec {

    public static String NAME = "RTNCalculator";

    CalculatorModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(double a, double b, Promise promise) {
        promise.resolve(a + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry because I am not fluent with react native and my skills in Android programming are now rusty, so take my words with caution: the error could be related with some kind of misconfiguration. It has been reported in different related contexts in several places like in [this article](https://medium.com/react-native-zone/english-bundling-failed-error-while-resolving-module-react-native-vector-icons-fontawesome-3958d7fa15ad).  Please, consider review the [linked Github issue](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/626#issuecomment-357405396) as well. I hope it helps.

Comment: @jccampanero I did check few of these kind of issues but they are for the old architecture of react native

Comment: I am sorry to hear that @Pritish. Please, forgive me, as I told, I am not used to using react native and the current Android libraries nowadays. I hope somebody shed some light into the issue.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is a react native issue introduced in 0.70 and was resolved in 0.71. Check [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35832) for more details

Comment: the link is broken